# Magento default Favicon appears when accessing direct directory

Tags: design, favicons

I am facing issue that when I am accessing a directory in magento like /media (Which is already secured by .htaccess file ) it is showing the default magento favicon even though my website's favicon is different.

E.g. Favicon displayed is magento's default where actually I want to change favicon to my website's favicon.

or Refer to Image :

[image]

I have tried to view source but no HTML source is available.

Any one suggest me how I can resolve this issue or how I can configure my favicon for this path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your root install magento you have a file called : "favicon.ico" if you view this file you see a Magento logo.

Change this file with your favicon and the problem solved.

Comment: I have done following changes already : changed root favicon images, skin/default favicon, skin/mytheme favicon file, backend/configration favicon file but nothing positive.

Comment: Clear cache and cookies of your browser